# How does a pure and an impure spectrum look like in optics?

Tags: optics, spectroscopy, dispersion

The following text is from *Concepts of Physics* by Dr. H.C.Verma, from the chapter "Dispersion and Spectra", page 436, topic "Spectrum", sub topic "Pure and Impure Spectrum":

> [...] In an ideal situation, light of one wavelength should occupy one particular spatial position in the spectrum. In such a case, no two wavelengths overlap in the dispersed beam. Each colour then gives its sharp impression. Such a spectrum is called a *pure spectrum*. [...]
>
> If the slit is wide, different points of the slit produce separate spectra which overlap each other. The colour impression gets diffused due to the overlap. Such a spectrum is called an impure spectrum.

There was an experimental setup in my book similar to the following one I found on the internet while searching regarding my doubt:

[image]

<sup>Image Source : [PhysicsMax.com](https://physicsmax.com/production-of-a-pure-spectrum-spectrometer-7030)</sup>

As far as I searched, I was unable to find any images depicting the visual difference between pure and impure spectrum. I'm unable to imagine how they will look like.

Since it was said for a pure spectrum - "*In an ideal situation...*" it suggests to me that obtaining a pure spectrum is highly difficult. So, I think the spectrum of visible light that we used to see from rainbows and prism are impure. But how exactly will a pure spectrum look like? Will that be discrete lines in the spectrum like an emission spectrum? Or will that have coloured bands with discrete dark lines demarcating different wavelengths which are too small to be noticeable (like an absorption spectrum)?

It'll much appreciated if you could include an image of a pure spectrum and an impure spectrum side by side, so that they could be visually inspected and differences could be perceived better.

I tried to learn more about these two types of spectrum on Wikipedia. But the article on [Spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum) doesn't have anything regarding this. Does it mean this kind of classification is out dated?

Comment: [Impure and pure spectrum](https://learnwithstudy.com/know-about-the-types-of-spectrum-impure-spectrum-and-pure-spectrum/)

Comment: https://www.astro.uu.se/~ulrike/Spectroscopy/PPT/Druckverbreiterung.GIF this picture shows broadening of spectrum line due to gas pressure. But the broadened lines look like just what an impure spectrum would look like. The key words for impure spectrum are "smear", "blur", "defuse", "overlap". To another question: Yes rainbow shows impure spectrum; this is due to the fact that sun is not a dot but a plate. (thinking the sun itself is a slit)

Comment: @Farcher: Thanks for sharing that link. However, it seems to be an alternate version of what I learnt in my book. Further, it doesn't seem to give a clear picture of the two types of spectrum.

Comment: @verdelite: Thanks for sharing the image. I didn't understand how the spectral lines broaden due to pressure, however I understood your point. The final version of your comment could be an answer, in my opinion.

Comment: Pressure dictates how frequently the atoms in your system collide with each other. And collision will scramble  the direction of emission. Thus broadening the spectra

Comment: @sammygerbil: Thanks for your comment. So, in a pure spectrum we could demarcate different colours much like different pots in your example. But the differences will be too small to be noticeable. Am I right?